# Why does the value of a local variable is not being initialised in try block.

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a local variable of Bool type initialised to FALSE. Am trying to set the value of this in the try block depending on certain condition. The condition is true, the value becomes true. When checked for the values inside the block and outside, they are different. Inside it is true and outside it takes the initialised value ie; false.

```
func  Print() ->  Bool{
    print(userName)
    print(password)
    var statusValue:Bool = False
    let request: Request = Request()
    let body: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    do{
    try request.post(url: url, body: body, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        if error != nil{
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        let statuscode = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            print("error:",error)
            print("status code:",statuscode?.statusCode)
        if statuscode?.statusCode == 200 {
            print("Success")
            statusValue = True
        }
        else{
            print("Fail")
        }
    })
    }
    catch{
        print("Not me error")
    }
    print("Printing status value outside:",statusValue)
   return statusValue
}
```

The value for "statusValue" prints different. Inside it sets to True, outside it prints False.

Comment: You read the variable before it is being set in a completion handler of the asynchronous block.

Comment: @EricAya i went through the post. It is returning data received, but i wish to pass the response. When i try to pass it in the jsonString(), its not allowing me to.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a value from a function works when your code is **synchronous** but in your case you're making a network request (**asynchronous** call) so the result will be available after some **milliseconds** or **seconds** then returning a value doesn't make any sense.

Instead you could "return" your result using **closures** like so:

```
func Print( completion: @escaping (_ statusValue: Bool) -> Void ) ->  Void {

  var statusValue:Bool = False
  let request: Request = Request()
  let body: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
  do{
    try request.post(url: url, body: body, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
      if error != nil{
        print(error?.localizedDescription)
        completion(false)
        return
      }

      let statuscode = response as? HTTPURLResponse

      if statuscode?.statusCode == 200 {
        print("Success")
        statusValue = True
        completion(statusValue)
      }
      else{
        completion(false)
      }
    })
  }
  catch{
    completion(false)
  }

}
```

---

When you call the function:

```
Print(completion: { statusValue in
  print(statusValue)
})
```